# Insert row using Entity Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two tables in my database

1. **State** (`stateid, statename`)
2. **City** (`cityid, stateid, cityname`)

I am using Entity Framework for my database access.

I want to insert data into the `City` table with the reference to the `State` table using Entity Framework

For that I wrote the following code

```
MyModel mdl = new MyModel();

City ct = new City();
ct.cityname = "Dallas";
ct.State = mdl.State.Where(u => u.stateid == 1);

mdl.AddToCity(ct);
mdl.SaveChanges();
```

There is data in the `State` table.

But I am the getting following error at `mdl.AddToCity(ct)`

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker

Answer (score 0):

Mind that the `Where` statement will return an `IEnumerable`. It is `. FirstOrDefault(u=>u.stateid==1)` (Or `SingleOrDefault`) you are after. I do not know if this will solve your problem though.
And did you give the `City` class a `State` property, not only a `stateid`?

Comment: I wrote the following code

ct.State = mdl.State.Where(u => u.stateid == 1).FirstOrDefault();

But i got same error